# pass variable from vba to javascript

Tags: javascript, vba

I am trying to change a class of element in vba, using executescript. My code is:

**bot.ExecuteScript**

```
("document.getElementById('img').setAttribute('style','newh1');")
```

This works fine but when I try to change the class to a variable named `varx`:

```vba
dim varx as string
varx="newh1"
bot.ExecuteScript ("document.getElementById('img').setAttribute('style', varx );")**
```

it comes an error saying "varx  not defined"

How can I solve this? Thanks

I searched stackoverflow but not found solution yet

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the value of `varx` into the js

`bot.ExecuteScript "document.getElementById('img').setAttribute('style', '" & varx & "');"`

You dont need the parentheses around the js unless there's a return value from `ExecuteScript` which you need to capture.

Comment: thanks for answering but this time gives javascript error: Invalid or unexpected token